# DbDataAdapter.Fill vs DataTable.Load in terms of memory requirements

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

I have an application that uses a dataadapter to fill a report. But because the data volume that must be contained in the report is huge, the application closes with an System.OutOfMemoryException. So, I consider using the DataTable.Load method to load a query with the specified data and then use that DataTable to create the report. How the Load method will work? Will it load all the data to memory or it will fetch data according to the available memory and the needs of the reporting tool? If the DataTable.Load method loads at once all the data and these stay permanent in-memory as the DbDataAdapter does then the Load method has not an advantage for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Question: what DbDataAdapter.Fill will create? A DataTable! So if it runs out of memory then DataTable.Load will run out of memory too. Just don't use them if you don't know (more or less) data size, much better to fill report chunk by chunk (with specific queries or using a reader to handle one row per time, for example; how to do it depends on technology you're using for your report).

Comment: Are you sure that the `OutOfMemoryException` is because there is too much data?  More often than not, it's an indication that you have run out of GDI or system objects, not physical memory.

Comment: How much data are you bringing back here? It usually isn't helpful to display millions of rows to a user, so you would typically aggregate *at the server* - once you've done that, OOM shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: `DataTable.Load` is a similar  to `DataAdapter.Fill`. So you will gain nothing in terms of memory consumption. The `DataTable` is an in-memory object with no lazy-load-capabilities. Why don't you use paging in your report? No user wants to see millions of records.

Comment: Not clear how you are building the report.  If you can use a DataReader then data is bought back a row at time.  DataTable has  lot of overhead - and a lot of features.

Comment: And what report engine are you using? Normally, you pass the query to the report and report engine should know how to process large amount of data.

Comment: I use DevXpress Xtrareports version 8 if that can help to have a better answer.  @StevenDoggart I think you have right but how can I control the number of GDI or system objects, all that I do is that I feed a reporting tool. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I've never used that reporting tool before and, even if I had, I don't know the specifics of how you are using it, so it's impossible to say.  However, it sounds to me like you are trying to generate an enormously large report and the report tool is poorly designed, in that it creates GDI objects for each datum in the report and doesn't release them until the report is closed.  There is a max limit of 10,000 GDI objects per process.  You can step through your code line by line and watch the GDI count as it goes up.

Comment: You can watch the GDI count by showing it in the task manager.  It is an optional column that you can choose to display on the processes tab.

Comment: @StevenDoggart without having test your advice yet, I already have noticed that even after the report has exported to a PDF the memory that my app uses is about 800MB while if I restart the app the memory used is some KBs. So I think that there should be a memory leak in the DevXpress tool.